# The subtle differences between undergo, experience and go through

Tags: phrase-choice

> Those who are living in apartments, sometimes may have to *experience* much decorating noise coming from their neighbors.

The definitions below are cited from Cambridge dictionary:

> Experience - If you experience something, it happens to you, or you feel it.
>   Go through - to experience a difficult or unpleasant situation.
>   Undergo - to experience something that is unpleasant or something that involves a change.

So I think it is fine to either use "undergo" or "go through" to replace "experience" in above sentence, but are there any subtle differences to use these alternatives?

Comment: This is an interesting question; I'm tempted to upvote it. It would've been much better, though, had you looked up these three words in a dictionary (perhaps you did, there's no way to know), and then included those definitions in your question (which you didn't). I have a hunch about how I'd use these three words, but I wouldn't want to leave incorrect information, and I don't have time to look them up right now. Moreover, I wouldn't want to waste time repeating what you already know. Have a look at how [this user asked a similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106200).

Comment: All right, it is a good idea to include their definitions here. Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Those who are living in apartments **sometimes** may have to *experience* much decorating noise coming from their neighbors.

It's *sometimes* because the experience is expected to happen at various times. Sometime would be used for a single instance

> I will go to the store **sometime** today.

*Undergo* is OK to use here, but it infers a negative or difficult experience.

> He has to **undergo** a difficult operation.
>
> All new recruits are required to **undergo** a physical examination.

*Go through* is more likely used related to a specific occurrence, so its not a good choice for your example.

> He had to **go through** the training program before he could be hired.

I like

> Those who are living in apartments sometimes may have to **endure** *a lot of* decorating noise coming from their neighbors.

The definition of [endure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/endure) sense 2 (*to put up with; tolerate*) fits the meaning in your example.

I'm not sure if its wrong, but *much* doesn't sound right in your statement. I prefer *a lot of*.

Comment: +1 for "endure".  (The bridge over the creek next to my office is being demolished and rebuilt; it is expected to take 10 months, and most of the time it will be noisy.  Endurance is surely what is needed.)